# Consulta sobre la direccion web que se ve en la barra del navegador

Tags: http

Tengo un hosting compartido y todos los dominios estan dentro de la carpeta public_html
dentro de esa carpeta hay varias subcarpetas.

Se que debo modificar algo en el htaccess, pero no encuentro que

Mi pagina esta dentro de public_html dentro de otra carpeta llamada "wp"

lo que quiero es que cuando la gente entre al sitio, en la barra de navegacion diga
www.godis.com.ar y no www.godis.com.ar/wp

Lo unico que logre es desde el hosting hacer que cuando la gente ponga www.godis.com.ar lo redirija a www.godis.com.ar/wp

Ahora como hago para que la gente no vea el /ps ni en la pagina princial ni en ningun momento que este navegando por la pagina???

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo tube el mismo problema. En mi hosting es un archivo que va dentro de la carpeta public_html. Se llama como bien dices *.htaccess*. Puedes forzar el acceso vía https utilizando el archivo .htaccess, si no tienes uno no hay problema, puedes añadir uno nuevo. También desde el panel desde acceso a ***SSL*** forzando el SSL.
Yo cree el archivo, creo que en tu hosting te dirán lo que debes de poner dentro del mismo, pues no se si lo que yo puse te servirá.
Se Crean tres líneas:
1-
2-
3-
Una debajo de otra y con los datos, sin dejar hueco entre líneas.
Prueba si te dicen lo que debes poner en el archivo, si no probamos a buscar lo mío.
Suerte.

Comment: Gracias Miguel, al primero que pregunte fue en el hostin y nunca me contestaron.

Comment: Bueno, busca en google que es lo que [debes poner](https://ticket.cdmon.com/es/support/solutions/articles/7000006237-información-y-usos-del-fichero-htaccess) yo encontre esto. Era algo asi: Pero en tre filas y con el numero delante: `1-RewriteEngine on
 
2- RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
 
3- RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|RewriteRule ^ http%1` Lo que yo puse en el mio no te servira me dijeron. De todas, no creo que pagues mucho por el hosting, no son muy formales. Yo [uso este](https://www.hostinger.es/) Suerte.

Comment: Gracias, no me sirvio pero sigo buscando

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que instalaste wordpress en un subdirectorio (wp) y no en directorio raíz, por eso al ingresar a [www.mipagina.com/](http://www.mipagina.com/) no carga ningún archivo pero si ingresas a [www.mipagina.com/wp](http://www.mipagina.com/wp) se carga el archivo index; como corregirlo, como mencionas puedes hacer una redireccion, reinstalar wordpress o mover los archivos a la raiz.

Saludos.